# Random glitch while playing YouTube video

Tags: video, graphics-card, gpu

I often find myself getting this kind of random glitch while playing YouTube videos.

[image]

It's either happen in the middle of a video (like the example above) or in the few first second of a video. When it is the latter, the video usually restarts for a few times then shows the typical YouTube error (video cannot be loaded).

As you can see from the thumbnail (and you can try [to open one example yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTFajxxPSb0&feature=youtu.be)), it's not the problem from the video. My uneducated guess is there is a problem with my GPU. But I don't know what to do.

My card is up-to-date and the problem mostly only come from playing YouTube video. I don't recall having this with media players (Windows Media Player or VLC) or image-editing/video-editing softwares like Photoshop or Corel Video Studio.

Comment: Try looking at other HTML5 videos online, like on Vimeo. If the same thing happens there it could be a problem with your browser.

Comment: If you force the video to a particular quality, using the cog -> 720p for example, do you still get the problem?